# How can I get an alert if my credit card balance goes above a certain number?

Tags: balance, alerts

I'm in the UK and occassionally I use a card for "non-routine purposes" (e.g. buying a laptop) that can push the card towards its (deliberately low) limit. I would like to get warnings before I get near this limit so that I can pay the balance ahead of time.

My bank offers notifications on purchases but does not seem to offer a "balance related notification". In the UK there is an oAuth-like protocol that alllows third parties like [snoop](https://snoop.app/) to receive some banking information to help you manage your accounts. Is there a way to get any such services to give me updates when an account goes above a certain level (or an alternative approach).

Comment: *"does not seem to offer a "balance related notification""* - Have you tried phoning them to verify this? All banks I've been with have offered "balance alerts" of some sort however the option to enable them often isn't very easy to find.

Comment: what is a "non-standard purpose"?

Comment: @user253751  I guess I mean "non-routine". So mostly I just buy groceries, and coffee. Sometimes I buy a new laptop, or tickets or book a hotel room. Let me update this.

Comment: The "looking for a product recommendation" cllosed question is kind of irritating. If you want to "do a thing" you always need a wayto do the thing. I don't really think the "looking for a recommendation" is reallly intended to close questions just because the solution might be a recommendation. Rather it is intended to make the question specific, llike this question. I want allerts when something happens. I don't care how.

Answer (score 2):

You're actually trying to solve the "wrong way" to do large purchases on a low limit credit card.

With a low limit credit card, you can prepay for large purchases.

If your card only has a 200£ limit, but if you need to buy a 3,000£ laptop, just put 3,000£ into the card couple days before the purchase and the excess balance will be available to the card.

This guarantees that you'll never have your card used for more than your limit without your direct input.

** This is from anecdotal experience. When I was in Canada, my card limit was only $300. When I needed to buy a nicer laptop after saving a year, I put couple extra thousand on my card and went out to buy the laptop. I called my card company just to let them know about the large purchase (so it doesn't get auto blocked due to irregular purchasing patterns), but the money was on the card so I didn't have to adjust the limit.

Comment: That's a reasonable idea. I'm not sure I can hae my card "in credit though" I might have look.

Comment: It's not possible to not support it. If you ever overpay your credit card bill, the company can't just take your money. It's your money and it has to be credited to you.

Answer (score 1):

One such app is **Mint**.  It allows you to link accounts and then set up custom notifications.  However it appears that this app may not be available to link to UK accounts.

**Plum** is an app that claims to be *one of the more advanced UK budgeting apps that you can use to help you save more and manage your money.*  It does seem more of a savings and investment app, but does claim to be the *best UK alternative to Mint budgeting app*, so may also have the notification features.

[withplum.com](https://withplum.com)

Comment: Thanks for you message. Just checking, just mint let you set up notifications if your balanced exceeds some number. I may well have a look at plumb this evening and report back.